# Rails: Error Messages Partial Not Rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can see in my console that the erorr_messages partial I made is getting rendered, and if a comment does not pass validations, then it will not be posted, but I can't get the actual error contents to render.

Error Partial:

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        The form contains <%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %>
    </div>
    <ul>
    <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

---

Comment form

```
<%= form_for @comment, url: comments_path do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
<%= f.hidden_field :post_id, value: post.id %>
<%= f.text_area :content, size: "60x2", placeholder: "Comment on this post..." %>
<%= f.submit "Comment" %>
```

---

Post Form

```
<%= form_for [@user, @post] do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
<%= f.text_area :content, size: "60x12", placeholder: "What do you want to say?" %>
<%= f.submit "Post" %>
```

---

Users/show

```
 <% if @user == current_user %>
<h4>Welcome <%= current_user.email %>! </h4>
<%= render "notifications" %>
<%= render 'shared/post_form' %> 
<%= render 'feed' %>
<% end %>
```

---

```
 class CommentsController < ApplicationController
def index
    @comments = Comment.all
end

def new
    @comment = Comment.new
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
end

def create
    @user = current_user
    @comment = @user.comments.build(comment_params)

    if @comment.save
        flash[:success] = "Comment Posted!"
        redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
    else
        flash[:danger] = "Could not post comment"
        redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
    end
end


private

def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:content, :user_id, :post_id)
end
end
```

---

```
 class PostsController < ApplicationController

def index
    @posts = Post.all
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @comment = Comment.new
end

def new
    @post = Post.new
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
end

def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
    if @post.save
        flash[:success] = "Posted!"
        redirect_to user_path(current_user)
    else
        flash[:danger] = "Post could not be submitted"
        redirect_to users_path
    end
end

private

def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:content)
end
end
```

Comment: Did you check the filename of your partial and it should be `_error_messages` and located to `app/views/shared`?

Comment: Yes i have named it that, and yes it is in that location as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `CommentsController#create`, when the save fails, rather than redirecting:

```
redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
```

Try staying on the same page and just rendering the "new" template:

```
render action: "new"
```

If you redirect, the browser will make a second request and `@comment` will get overwritten with a freshly-built Comment.

If you stay on the same page and render the "new" template, it will use the `@comment` instance that's already loaded and which failed to save (this instance has all the validation errors set on it).

P.S. the flash message works because that's what `flash` is for - a way to store messages in your session so that they survive across redirects.

Comment: the only issue with this is that I don't have a template for a new.html.erb because I have just been using the _comments_form.html.erb partial

Comment: Ah, gotcha!  In that case, the easiest option is to put the validation error messages in the flash: `flash[:danger] = "Could not post comment: #{@comment.errors.full_messages}".  The more complex option would be to use [jquery_ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki) and [rails' data: remote forms](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html)

Comment: rock on man great idea putting it in the flash! thanks for your help!